# How to launch jar with 'exec app_process' on android ICS

Tags: android, process, jar, classloader

I have 3 devices.

1.base on cm9(android 4.0.4).

2.htcg14(android 4.0.3)

3.moto me525 base on miui(android 2.2)

they are all rooted.

I exec the code below in the terminal on device 1 and 3,the process works fine.
But device 2,it doesn't work.

```
su
export CLASSPATH=/sdcard/foo.jar
exec app_process /system/bin xx.xx.Test '$@'
```

log

```
W/dalvikvm(12364): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Ljava/lang/System;
W/dalvikvm(12364): Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Ljava/lang/ClassLoader$SystemClassLoader;
W/dalvikvm(12364): WARNING: system class loader is NULL (setting main ctxt)
W/dalvikvm(12364): Warning: tracked references remain post-initialization
W/dalvikvm(12364): MAIN reference table (0xf9a388) dump:
W/dalvikvm(12364):   Last 1 entries (of 1):
E/dalvikvm(12364): Class lookup Ljava/lang/Daemons; attempted with exception pending
W/dalvikvm(12364): Pending exception is:
I/dalvikvm(12364): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:125)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(12364): Caused by:
I/dalvikvm(12364): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.createSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:100)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.access$000(ClassLoader.java:65)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.ClassLoader$SystemClassLoader.<clinit>(ClassLoader.java:81)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:125)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(12364): Caused by:
I/dalvikvm(12364): java.lang.NullPointerException:
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:365)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.System.initSystemProperties(System.java:286)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.System.getProperties(System.java:260)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:425)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:406)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.System.<clinit>(System.java:90)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.createSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:100)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.access$000(ClassLoader.java:65)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.ClassLoader$SystemClassLoader.<clinit>(ClassLoader.java:81)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:125)
I/dalvikvm(12364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(12364): DALVIK THREADS:
I/dalvikvm(12364): (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
I/dalvikvm(12364): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(12364):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40aa1490 self=0xf99d30
I/dalvikvm(12364):   | sysTid=12364 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074107592
I/dalvikvm(12364):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=18 stm=7 core=0
I/dalvikvm(12364):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(12364): 
E/dalvikvm(12364): VM aborting
F/libc    (12364): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
I/DEBUG   ( 4218): debuggerd: 2012-08-02 14:29:57
I/DEBUG   ( 4218): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 4218): Build fingerprint: 'htc_asia_tw/htc_pyramid/pyramid:4.0.3/IML74K/391535.6:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 4218): pid: 12364, tid: 12364  >>> app_process <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 4218): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
```

When I exec these code in java,device 1 and 2 don't work.They have the same error.About device 3,I don't know the result,because someone get back his device.

help!any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like that when launching dalvikvm, your **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** is not correctly set in the environment.
In ICS & JB, dalvikvm requires **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** to have certain path in it. The default is `/vendor/lib:/system/lib`, although usually `/system/lib` is enough. Else you would see the exception.

You may try to add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib` after the `su` command in your script.

If your euid does not match your uid, **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** may be stripped from the environment. You can use `id` and `id -r` after `su` to check if they match. You may also check if `/system/bin/mksh` is setuid'ed, since this may also cause the problem.