# Using adb to broadcast intent with extras

Tags: android, android-intent, adb, root, broadcast

### background

i wish to send a broadcast intent (even with root permission) that an app was removed, and for this, i have to broadcast an intent with extras.

### problem

i just can't figure out what am i missing, since i can't find the correct way to do it.

### what i've done so far

i think I've found where on android the OS broadcasts the intent (the file is called "PackageManagerService.java" ). I've also found out how to get the correct permission using root (and it works) , and also how to put extra data into the intent of the broadcast (link [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/622698abc/archive/2013/06/11/3132306.html)) , all using the "adb" tool.

now i have to put all of the pieces together.

the code so far is :

```
String packageOfCurrentApp=..., packageOfAppToReportAbout=... ;
try
  {
  final java.lang.Process p=
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
          String.format("su -c pm grant %s android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED",packageOfCurrentApp));
  final int res=p.waitFor();
  Logger.log(LogLevel.DEBUG,"got permission:"+(res==0));
  if(res==0)
    {
    final java.lang.Process p2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(//
            "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED "+//
            "--ei android.intent.extra.UID -1 "+//
            "-eez android.intent.extra.DATA_REMOVED true"+//
            " -d com.syncme.syncmeapp ");
    final int res2=p2.waitFor();
    Logger.log(LogLevel.DEBUG,"broadcast?"+(res2==0));
    }
  }
catch(final Exception e)
  {
  Logger.log(LogLevel.DEBUG,"error:"+e);
  }
```

the permission getting works, but the broadcasting doesn't.

### question

what is wrong with the code? what is missing? how can i fix it?

i would also like to know how to do the same via the shell (of the PC).

Answer (score 0):

Like for battery :-
we use below
m broadcast "intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED;i.status=5;i.voltage=4155;i.level=100;end"

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the source code of PackageManagerService.java

```
        Bundle extras = new Bundle(1);
        extras.putInt(Intent.EXTRA_UID, removedUid);
        extras.putBoolean(Intent.EXTRA_DATA_REMOVED, false);
        sendPackageBroadcast(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED, removedPackage,
                extras, null, null);
```

Comment: i have . i already wrote about it. since apps can't have this permission using the normal way, i can't just write this code and need to use adb commands using ROOT.

Comment: You can try to write these java code and compile them into a jar file. And in your application, fork, su, write 'app_process xxx' to execute the jar file as root.

Comment: i didn't know that. can you please explain more? also, if there is an easier way, please tell me about it too.

Comment: Please check the answer of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773506/how-to-launch-jar-with-exec-app-process-on-android-ics